# Big O of clojure library functions

Tags: clojure, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Can anyone point me to a resource that lists the Big-O complexity of basic clojure library functions such as conj, cons, etc.? I know that Big-O would vary depending on the type of the input, but still, is such a resource available? I feel uncomfortable coding something without having a rough idea of how quickly it'll run.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a table composed by [John Jacobsen](http://eigenhombre.com) and taken [from this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/clojure/xpqap7HShWw):

[image]

Comment: An "1" in quotes, is that close enough to one to not matter (according to Rich Hickey.) But really is O(log_32 depth)?

Comment: This table is not entirely correct. `last` is always O(n). `cons` is always O(1) (assuming `seq` is always O(1)). `conj` in a vector is only "1", not 1.

Comment: @kotarak Would you be able to elaborate a little on your corrections? :)

Comment: @Anonymous `last` creates a sequence and walks it. Hence, O(n). `cons` just creates a Cons object and calls `seq` on its second arg. So as long as `seq` is O(1), `cons` is O(1). `conj` on a vector is "usually" O(1), but at some point arrays have to be moved around under the hood. So worst-case is O(log32 n) aka. O("1").

Comment: @Anonymous And another correction. `get` doesn't work on sequences.

Comment: I'm the author of the table above and indeed it was my first stab at summarizing my imperfect knowledge at the time -- http://www.innoq.com/blog/st/2010/04/clojure_performance_guarantees.html looks to be more definitive.

Answer (score 13):

Late to the party here, but I found [the link in the comments of the first answer](http://www.innoq.com/blog/st/2010/04/clojure_performance_guarantees.html) to be more definitive, so I'm reposting it here with a few modifications (that is, `english->big-o`):

[image]
[Table Markdown source](https://stackedit.io/viewer#!url=https://gist.github.com/brymck/8266276/raw/clojure_big_o.md)

On unsorted collections, O(log<sub>32</sub>n) is nearly constant time, and because 2<sup>32</sup> nodes can fit in the bit-partitioned [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) nodes, this means a [worst-case complexity of log<sub>32</sub>2<sup>32</sup> = 6.4](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=vZYfAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT60&ots=1aPHhxVo55&dq=%22near-constant%20time%22&pg=PT63#v=onepage&q=%22near-constant%20time%22&f=false). Vectors are also [tries where the indices are keys](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-2).

Sorted collections utilize binary search where possible. (Yes, these are both technically O(log n); including the constant factor is for reference.)

Lists guarantee constant time for operations on the first element and O(n) for everything else.